How do I guarantee generic to extend specific class safely in Kotlin?
I wanted to create my own Map class which allows only Number class (i.e. Int, Long, Double, ...). Also if value in entry becomes zero, it will automatically remove that entry from map. As I'm not familiar with generics in Kotlin, keep in mind that I might have written class in correctly, but below is the code that I wrote
class PositiveMap<K, V> : HashMap<K, V>() where V : Number {
    override fun put(key: K, value: V): V? {
        val isZero = when (value) {
            is Byte -> value == 0.toByte()
            is Short -> value == 0.toShort()
            is Int -> value == 0
            is Long -> value == 0L
            is Float -> value == 0f
            is Double -> value == 0.0
            is BigInteger -> value == BigInteger.ZERO
            is BigDecimal -> value == BigDecimal.ZERO
            else -> false
        }

        // Don't put value at all if value was zero, and there was no such key
        if (!containsKey(key) && isZero) {
            return null
        }

        val old = super.put(key, value)

        // Remove entry if value turned out to be zero
        if (isZero) {
            remove(key)

However, IDE warns me that for each case, checking if value is zero always returns false

I tried to add some bit dirty check like below, then IDE warns that value indeed is Number class

So I just decided to create test unit code, and check if it works fine or not
class TestUnit {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            // Putting PositiveMap<String, String> shows error as intended
            val map = PositiveMap<String, Long>()

            map["hello"] = 1L

            println(map["hello"])
            println(map.containsKey("hello"))

            map["hello"] = (map["hello"] ?: 0L) - 1L

            println(map["hello"])
            println(map.containsKey("hello"))
        }
    }
}

Output was like below
1
true
null
false

This output started to make me feel that IDE is just showing false-positive warnings. However, as I stated above, I'm not familiar with generics, so I can't assure myself that it's bug of IDE.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and below is version info

and below is Kotlin version that I'm using

Is this false positive warn (likely a bug), or is there any way to remove warning that IDE is giving?
EDIT:
I tried to put value <= 0 for each case instead, then this removes the warnings. However, I still wonder why checking exact zero warns me

This is more likely than not, just an IntelliJ bug.

the problem is that the compiler is not able to smart-cast value in those branches. If you switch to the new K2 compiler (which has become stable with Kotlin 2.0.0), the warning disappears

Thanks all you guys, as @user2340612 mentioned, I tried K2 compiler, and it removed the warnings! You can write an answer to get accepted, or I will write answer by myself

It looks like the old version of the Kotlin compiler (used by IntelliJ  to inspect the code) is not able to realise that in those when branches the value variable can safely be smart-casted to the corresponding type. This is likely to be caused by a limitation with the existing version of the compiler and appears to be fixed with the new K2 compiler.
If you enable K2 mode in the IDE, you'll see the value variable will be smart-casted to the correct type, and the corresponding warning disappears.
Please note that even though the K2 compiler is stable, IntelliJ IDEA is currently still using the old compiler for syntax highlighting, inspections, etc because "K2 mode" is still in Alpha – see here. You can enable "K2 mode" in IntelliJ 2024.1 (or newer), but please be aware that

The performance and stability of code highlighting and code completion have been significantly improved, but not all IDE features are supported yet.


I'm finding that the Kotlin compiler itself (i.e. the kotlinc command line) doesn't issue any warnings, even earlier versions. It's only the IDE that gives these warnings.

that's correct. What the IDE is highlighting is the result of an "inspection", so technically it's an IDE hint rather than a compiler warning. However, the IDE is using the compiler under the hood to evaluate those inspections, so the actual "fix" for this problem is just to enable "K2 mode" in the IDE. I updated my answer to clarify that point
